# jenkins build stalls with Cannot contact node_name java.lang.InterruptedException

Tags: jenkins

A job on a node stalls with following exception

```
Cannot contact W_64_10: java.lang.InterruptedException
```

This exception happens at random times. During script execution, in between, with or without heavy load or disk utilization.

Setup is a node running on a local host as qemu/kvm. Here a Windows 10, but this error occures independend of the machines.

The errormessage is the last one received, execution stalls, no error, no abbort, just blocking without noticed by jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

... a sleepless night later:

There was actually **no disc space left on the host system for the qemu node**. The jenkins agent has seen a free disk but was not able to write cause auf the missing host space. This might be also a bug in not aborting, on server or client side or at least a missing feature.